# error coming while making a view in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, templates, backbone.js

Here i want to make a view in backbone.js

```
// The DOM element for a User item...
    var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
        //... is a list tag.
        tagName:  "li",
         // Cache the template function for a single item.
        template: _.template($('#tmpl_occupant').html()),

        // a one-to-one correspondence between a **User** and a **UserView** in this
        // app, we set a direct reference on the model for convenience.
        initialize: function() {

            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'close');
            this.model.bind('change', this.render);
            this.model.view = this;
        },
        // Re-render the contents of the User item.
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
```

This view code i put in the user.js and when index.html load it is called and it gives error

```
str is null
http://myserver/rahul/js/underscore-1.1.3.js
Line 675
```

i think it is due to because error not come when i remove this line

```
  template: _.template($('#tmpl_occupant').html()),


<script type="text/html" id="tmpl_occupant">
    <%=user.username%> is in <%=gib.name%> (<%=channel%>)
    </script>
```

i think it is because index.html is not completely loaded while this line is executed .so it don't fine tmpl_occupant , what can i do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it by passing directly string instead of jquery reference.
or

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template
and better solution is to compile the template and pass the template to the instance of view.

Comment: i didn't get it right. how can i pass a string instead of jquery reference? i'm also using this on my code template : _.template($("tpl-item-list").html()),

Answer (score 3):

*What can i do to solve this problem?*

First, you can move your initialization script to the bottom of your HTML document.  That ensures that it will be run after all of the HTML is loaded.

Otherwise, you can wrap your initialization code in a `$(document).ready()` block, which will ensure that the document is fully loaded and the HTML is available.  My code looks something like this:

```
ApplicationController = Backbone.Controller.extend({
    /* router code here */
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    myapp = new ApplicationController()
});
```

This uses jQuery's DOM ready event to make sure that everything is ready before running the first line of client code.

Comment: Also you have to initialize the template in the initialize function.

Comment: Julien: Why?  Rahul is using underscore.js templates; they don't need much initializing other than being pulled out of the DOM into an HTML string.  If the template is embedded in the document, as I frequently do using the script tag, then it's present when the DOM tree is active.

Comment: His template attributes is looking into the DOM to load the template.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right.  Sorry.  I have the good habit of putting my templates before my code invocations.